# Overlay color and background image on the same div

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-color

Is this possible? To have a background-color overlay *and* background-image all on one div? As in:

```css
div {
  color: white;
  background-color: hsla(15, 92%, 13%, 0.79);
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/500x500');
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pseudo element like this :

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/500x500');
  height: 500px;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: hsla(15, 92%, 13%, 0.79);
  z-index: 0;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  color: white;
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/500x500');
  background-color: hsla(15, 92%, 13%, 0.79);
  background-blend-mode: overlay;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
</div>
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: why not using his color so we can see the result better :)